# Visual Studio Project Template With Glob Folder Links

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, project-template

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio 2013 custom project template that creates multiple projects.  I'm having an issue because one of the projects has a glob include path to the other:

```
<Content Include="..\Project1\Content\**\*.*">
  <Link>Content\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
```

The wizard to create the project seems to go through the path piece by piece (.., Project1, Content, **, *.*) and tries to create a file on disk. The problem is that '*' is an invalid file character.

Is there any way to accomplish this?  Do I need to remove this from my template CSPROJ file and manually add it in the template wizard?